# Event fire in firefox

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using a piece of code in JavaScript as:

```
if (td_sel.addEventListener) {
    //alert('event listener');
    td_sel.addEventListener("click" , function() { DeleteRow(selected_val) }, false);
}
```

where `td_sel` is the `td` element created dynamically.

This is not working in Firefox. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is it working? What error messages are reported by Firefox (ideally by Firebug, which you should install if you haven't already)

Comment: Any message from the firebug. have you tried debugging it. I am seeing that the semicolon `;` is missing. `function(){DeleteRow(selected_val);}`, but i don't know if its the issue.

Comment: @Talha, semicolon is not an issue in such constructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine. The only thing is that maybe `DeleteRow` function is in other scope then posted code.